# Solr getting prevous search results

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I am new to solr. Is it possible in solr to get previously search result using id? For example I search for gender Female and age above 21. In future can I get this search result using some id ? Without storing in db.

Answer (score 0):

No, not without middleware (I'm not familiar with any existing that offers this, so you might have to create it yourself).